# How can i group unordered list?

Tags: javascript, c#

How can i group unorderd List? I have the following for-each to display RP informations but it creates a duplicate with the same Name, How can i group the li items by Name?

```
<ul id="treeview">
     @foreach (var item in Info)
        {
          <li data-expanded="true">@item.PaName
                <ul>
                     <li data-expanded="true">@item.sName</li>
                 </ul>
           </li>
         }
  </ul>
```

I want to see something like this

```
----AOC
     ---DBSR
     ---KOLC
```

Answer (score 0):

Just group data by PartyName, then you got data with key is PartyName and value is list of objects have the same PartyName. Use it to display in view instead.

Comment: Hi Rem, What do you mean by group data by PartyName, you mean in C# using linq?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C# but the idea is processing logic data into prefer structure you prefer first and then display in your view. And  i think u should do it in pure C# (May be use DICTIONARY to store it?? ). Hope this can help u.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track talking about LINQ. In a basic form your code could look like this:

```
using System.Linq

groupedData = data.GroupBy(x => x.PartyName)
```

The output will be in this structure

```
"AOC" : [
    {
        "SubPartyName": "DBSR",
        "OtherData": "...."
    },
    {
        "SubPartyName": "KOLC",
        "OtherData": "...."
    },
]
```

You could then loop through the grouped data in your view.

Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: Thanks Sam, but `System.InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported.` --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357820/using-groupby-in-linq-client-side-groupby-is-not-supported

Comment: I've added answer to that question as well since that exception is related to entity framework which isn't relevant to this specific question

Answer (score 0):

> I have the following for-each to display RP informations but it creates a duplicate with the same PartyName, How can i group the li items by PartyName?

You can try following code snippet:

```
@model IEnumerable<Party>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "RParty";
    var rpInfo = Model.GroupBy(p=>p.PartyName);
}

<h1>RP Information</h1>

<ul id="treeview">
    @foreach (var item in rpInfo)
    {
        <li data-expanded="true">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>@item.Key

            @foreach (var party in @item)
            {
                <ul>
                    <li data-expanded="true">
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i> @party.SubPartyName
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }

        </li>
    }
</ul>
```