# Using GroupBy in Linq: Client side GroupBy is not supported

Tags: c#, linq

How can i use Linq and group a list? I have the following linq expression to get data from the database, how can i modify my code to group results by PartyName Field?

```
var RParty = await context.Parties
                           .Where(b => b.ID == request.ID)
                           .ToListAsync();
```

I tried

```
   var RParty = await context.Parties
                               .Where(b => b.ID == request.ID)
                               .GroupBy(b => b.PartyName)
                               .ToListAsync();
```

But i get this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported.
```

Comment: Where is `context.Parties` coming from?

Comment: Did you Google for `System.InvalidOperationException: Client side GroupBy is not supported.`?

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/934#issuecomment-552487819 ?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the github link posted by mjwills, the issues here is there are two different GroupBys you could be executing, a SQL Group By, or a C# LINQ Group By.

One solution here is to switch the order of your calls:

```
var RParty = await context.Parties
                           .Where(b => b.ID == request.ID)
                           .ToListAsync()
                           .GroupBy(b => b.PartyName); // <-- move after ToList
```

By calling ToList the data will be treated as a C# type and the LINQ GroupBy function should work.

However, you need to be careful because once you call ToList the data will be returned from the database and be stored in memory on the server. Depending on how large the Parties table is expected to be it could cause performance issues

Comment: Thanks Sam I get this error " doesnt not contain definition of GroupBY error and no accessible extention method by 'GroupBy' accepting first argument of Type <Task<list<parties>> could be found .. are you missing a directive"

Comment: have you imported linq? using System.Linq

Comment: Sam, Yes i did import linq

Comment: Perhaps try `ToList` rather than `ToListAsync`.